# passing parent object automatically

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

So I have a couple of classes

```
function BaseClass(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function ImageClass(img, w, h, x, y){
    BaseClass.call(this, x, y);
    this.img = img;
}
ImageClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.protoype);
ImageClass.prototype.constructor = ImageClass;

function LayerClass(img, w, h, x, y){
    ImageClass.call(img, w, h, x, y);
    this.collection = [];
    this.createSprite = function(img, r, a, w, h, x, y){
        this.collection.push(new Sprite(img, r, a, w, h, x, y));
    }
}
LayerClass.prototype = Object.create(ImageClass.prototype);
LayerClass.prototype.constructor = LayerClass;

function SpriteClass(img, r, a, w, h, x, y){
    ImageClass.call(img, w, h, x, y);
    this.r = r;
    this.a = a;
}
SpriteClass.prototype = Object.create(ImageClass.prototype);
SpriteClass.prototype.constructor = SpriteClass;
```

In my code each of the inherited classes uses call() to pass 'this'

The problem being is that if I have a Layer object that contains any Sprite objects, I would like the Sprite objects to have a parent (super) reference and I can't do this because the class constructors use this to set properties.

So does anyone know how I could pass the parent or (and I know this is going to sound dumb, it's late) be able to get the parent scope this in the class constructor?

While writing this I realized that it might be as simple as setting the parent property after the object is set as a child but I'm looking for confirmation if that's the best way or if anyone knows something better. Also feel free to tell me I know nothing about prototype because I'm still learning it. :-)

-Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand the issue. Please clarify *"I would like the Sprite objects to have a parent (super) reference and I can't do this because the class constructors use this to set properties."*. Note that some of your calls are wrong. E.g. `ImageClass.call(img, w, h, x, y);` should be `ImageClass.call(this, img, w, h, x, y);`.

Comment: I rewrote the basic structure from scratch into stackoverflow so I may have flubbed a thing or two. I mainly need to be able to access the dimensions  of the layer object parent, for example, to be able to relatively size and position a sprite child.

Comment: I still don't understand why you cannot pass the layer as argument to `Sprite` or create a method on `Sprite.prototype` that allows to the set the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? Its not automatic, but still works. Javascript does not have native support for classes, so it has its limitations.

```
function LayerClass(img, w, h, x, y){
    ImageClass.call(img, w, h, x, y);
    this.collection = [];
    this.createSprite = function(img, r, a, w, h, x, y){
        var spriteObj = new Sprite(img, r, a, w, h, x, y);
        spriteObj.parent = this;
        this.collection.push(spriteObj);
    }
}
```

You will be able to access the parent variable of spriteObject.

Also, if you are looking for inheritance, try coffee script. It compiles back to javascript and handles most of the inheritance problems for you.

Comment: Yea, I theorized this would be a solution.
At least someone confirmed it for me, thank you.

Comment: *"Also, if you are looking for inheritance, try coffee script. "* Eh, if you are going to use a preprocessor anyway, go with the next JS version which introduces `class`: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#classes.

Comment: I know, I was excited for that but its not until summer and even then I suspect that support will only be FF and Chrome